# Downgrade from VS Enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-2015, enterprise

I had VS 2015 Enterprise trial, and now the trial is over I want to go back to Community, is all I can do uninstall Enterprise and install Community, or is it possible to enter a Community key so I wont have to reinstall VS?

Comment: You need to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: That takes so freaking long :/

Comment: Do it overnight, it's not that bad...

Comment: do you know if it keeps the settings and the extensions you had installed?

Answer (score 2):

If you had previously install 'Community', you just need to uninstall 'Enterprise' to continue working with 'Community'.

Took ~10 mins on my machine.